# Deducing type from pointer using decltype

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, decltype

VS2015 is throwing a lot of errors when trying to execute this code:

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
std::vector<decltype(*p)> v;
```

However, when I check the type returned by this decltype I get an int!

```
typeid(decltype(*p)) == typeid(int) // returns true
```

Can anyone explain it to me? I did the workaround by simply dereferencing pointer and decltyping the value I got. But why isn't it possible to do it by dereferencing pointer directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an alternative to the solution proposed by @Brian, you can use:

```
std::vector<std::remove_reference<decltype(*p)>::type> v;
```

You can also use:

```
std::vector<std::remove_pointer<decltype(p)>::type> v;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::decay<decltype(*p)>::type> v3;
```

Comment: Or `remove_pointer<decltype(p)>`, which is *three* characters shorter :)

Comment: @Barry Or `decay<decltype(*p)>` :) 8 characters shorter, and handles `const int *` correctly.

Answer (score 5):

`decltype(*p)` is `int&`, not `int`, and you can't have a vector of references. The unfortunately named `typeid` doesn't expose this difference since it strips references and cv-qualifiers.

This works though:

```
 std::vector<decltype(a)> v;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! can you give me the reason why it returns int& and not an int? is there any logic behind it?

Comment: But the question was how to deduce the type from a pointer, which `a` isn't.

Comment: @greenshade The logic is a bit convoluted. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype#Explanation